# Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I just started the project in Jupyter Notebook by requesting the "option" elements under a specific "select" element. But I failed to continue because of the attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'. And the same thing happened to me in other projects as well. Does anyone know why this happened? Really appreciate it.

Below is my code:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://www.factsonline.nl/browse-chemical-accidents-in-database/'

r=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

option_elements=soup.find('select', id='pckCountry').find_all('option')
```

Then comes the error.

Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the source of `http://www.factsonline.nl/browse-chemical-accidents-in-database/`, I cannot find element with `id="pckCountry"`. Is the selector correct?

Comment: This select is only visible when you are clicking on Keyword search button. If you want to get the list of countries ten you have to use `selenium` because first you have to open the page then click on KeywordSearch  button to render the page and get this particular select values

Comment: Thank you both! I fixed the problem.